# Substitute a Java API class with custom class?

Tags: java, android, reflection

I have a closed source Android program that uses the `android.opengl.GLSurfaceView` class.

I need to inject some Java code (injection already done) which substitutes all `android.opengl.GLSurfaceView` related processing with my own `GLSurfaceView` class (hooking) with no changes to original code (no sources, no disassemble allowed).

Basically it's a sort of API hooking in terms of Win32 C programming but in Java/Android.

Comment: Yes. I adds my activity and rearranges it to be the first. Later my activity starts the original one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do this using Java reflection.

Your best bet is to use a bytecode rewriting mechanism to modify the bytecode of the closed-source program.  If you were using "real Java", I'd suggest BCEL.  You need to deal with Davlik code, and I don't know if there is a BCEL analog for Davlik.

This assumes that you have access to the bytecodes of this closed-source application in a form that allows you to tinker with them without violating security rules.  For instance, if the application has been signed, then changing bytecodes will invalidate the signature.

And doing this without violating a restriction on reverse engineering would another difficulty.

---

Sounds like you need to give up on this idea.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid no real hooking is possible. I can parse APK to "smali" set, change appropriate referncies and rebuild. But this is well too dramatic changes to the original APK. I'd like to do it other way...

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this, and the reason you can't is that it would be a huge violation of security. For example if there were a mechanism to do this, you would be able to override the classes that prevent a downloaded Java app from, say, installing malware on your computer.

You can do this by modifying the bytecode of your installation so that GLSurfaceView does something different, or by modifying the bytecode of the app so that it calls a substitute class instead of GLSurfaceView.

Comment: That's what I'm failing to understand. If I can modify bytecode so easy (and I did it) why I'm forbidden to do it 'legally'? Why not to extend Reflection mechanism further?

Comment: You can modify bytecode only on a machine you control - so you can only violate your own security. If you allowed it programmatically I could modify your machine's bytecode and breach your security.

Answer (score 0):

If the class of you want to inject the code are not a final class, you can extends the class and reimplement the methods of you need (again, only if the method are not final method)

Comment: As far as I understand the situation the class "GLSurfaceView" is not final. I can build an extender class but how the original source code will 'know' to use the extender and not the original class? I cannot modify the original sources.